# Quitar o modificar fecha inferior datetimepicker vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

me gustaría saber si se puede quitar o modificar la fecha inferior que sale al desplegar un datetimepicker en vb.net (la que sale "Hoy: 13/01/2022").
He podido ver ejemplos donde esa fecha aparece y otros en los que no aparece, pero no he encontrado documentación alguna sobre cómo manipular ese elemento del control. Tampoco se como identificarlo, quizá por eso no encuentro nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Hola Alfabravo, gracias por los consejos! El tema es que no hay código que enseñar, simplemente, no he encontrado ninguna documentación que diga si se puede manipular ese elemento del control, sin embargo si he visto algunos ejemplos en los que esa fecha aparece y otros en los que no aparece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buscando he encontrado que sí es posible quitar la fecha inferior del DateTimePicker.
Para quitarlo hay que añadir una clase al proyecto que herede de DateTimePicker. La he nombrado XJDatePicker.

1. Agregarle el código siguiente:

   ```
    Public Class XJDatePicker
        Inherits Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
        Const DTM_FIRST As Int32 = &H1000
        Const DTM_SETMCSTYLE As Int32 = DTM_FIRST + 11
        Const DTM_GETMCSTYLE As Int32 = DTM_FIRST + 12
        Const MCS_NOTODAYCIRCLE As Int32 = &H8
        Const MCS_NOTODAY As Int32 = &H10
        Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleCreated(e As EventArgs)
            Dim style As Int32 = SendMessage(Me.Handle, DTM_GETMCSTYLE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
            style = style Or MCS_NOTODAY Or MCS_NOTODAYCIRCLE
            SendMessage(Me.Handle, DTM_SETMCSTYLE, IntPtr.Zero, CType(style, IntPtr))
            MyBase.OnHandleCreated(e)
        End Sub
        <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
        Public Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, msg As Int32, wp As IntPtr, lp As IntPtr) As Int32
        End Function
    End Class
   ```
2. Compilar el proyecto
3. Agregar el control XJDatePicker al formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. Ejecuta la aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias Xavier, probado y funciona, crack!

Answer (score 0):

Esto es sencillo solo con MinDate
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Now

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el MaxDate seria suficiente
dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Now;

Comment: revisando bien tu pregunta, quieres que las fechas hacia adelante no se visualizen en ese caso seria el MaxDate

Comment: Hola Alexander, gracias por responder. En principio las dos opciones que me daban era modificar la fecha expuesta como TODAY para que ponga una fecha infinita (01/01/9999, por ejemplo) para facilitar cierta funcionalidad a los usuarios, en principio no parece posible. Y la otra opción era quitar esa fecha y es la que he tomado.